# Gmail Calendar - Popup Notifications not working

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

I'm getting email notifications, but no pop-ups on Windows-10 desktop (in Chrome), and nothing on my Android smart phone.  I'm afraid to missing meetings now after relying on this feature.

My Primary Calendar settings are as follows: 
[image]

The General/Event Settings are: 
[image]

Comment: Missing calendar notif on windows 10: this solved my issue 1) on google calendar settings enabling notification (from a shared calendar)  2) (optional) reset the windows calendar app https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/56782-calendar-notifications-stopped-working-appearing.html

Answer (score 4):

All of these options are definitely worth trying.

What worked for me is to actually just have Google Calendars open in a tab. Having it open while on mail.google.com is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some issue with your browser's setting.

From [Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> **Didn’t get a notification**
>
> 1. First, make sure notifications are turned on for your calendar using the steps [Turn notifications on or off](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).
> 2. Check that you’ve chosen to show notifications in your browser’s permission settings. If not, turn on desktop notifications.
>
> **In Chrome**
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click More More and then **Settings**.
> 3. At the bottom of the page click Advanced (Down Arrow).
> 4. Under "Privacy and security," click **Content Settings**.
> 5. Click **Notifications**.
> 6. Next to "Allow," click **Add**.
> 7. Enter calendar.google.com and then click **Add**.

Comment: While the first step of turning on notifications is necessary, I don't know if the second is. I thought this had worked for me but it didn't. See my answer for what worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure Focus Assist is set to OFF in Windows 10, else your Desktop Notifications wont pop up on the screen and you can only be able to see them in the Action Center.  Go to the bottom right of your screen, right click on the Action Center > Focus Assist > OFF.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I had calendar.google.com blocked in Edge.  Check here if you are using edge:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  My problem was notification settings on desktop.  See if this helps: Go to Windows Settings >> System >> Notifications and Actions.  Under "Notifications" area make sure "Get notifications from apps and other senders" is turned ON.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to enable desktop notifications from the Google Calendar settings.